# PERMANOVA test and its assumptions

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, likert, permutation-test, order-statistics

I have collected data based on a 5 point Likert scale (very low, low, neutral, high, very high) on factors considered by individuals before making investment decisions. There are five factors (D.Vs) influencing investment decisions.

I am interested in knowing whether there is a significant difference in preference level of male and female (IVs) for the above said factors. Number of males is 252 and of females is 98.

I have applied Permutational Manova in adonis function of R, since data are ordinal in nature, and the result is not significant.

I have read that the permutation test is non-parametric. Does for the permutation test equality of variance is highly important.

Also the computation of mean, SD and variance are discouraged by many scholars for ordinal data.

Can you throw some light on the permutation test and its assumptions and on violations of those?

Comment: DVs means "dependent variables"; the variables so described here sound like predictors.

Comment: Male and Female are predictors/ independent variables. Five dependent variables are there, namely tax benefits, steady return, safety of capital,rate of return and wealth creation, which influences the investment decisions of individuals. Individuals were asked to rate on likert scale, to which factor they give highest preference, before making investment decisions. I want to analyze if male and female groups give same preference to each factor or they differs in their behavior.

Answer (score 2):

No, PERMANOVA does not require homogeneity of variances, so long as your study has a balanced design (the test is very robust to heterogeneity of variance for experiments with balanced design).

You can use ordinal data in PERMANOVA, such as responses to questionnaires, and it is not based on comparison of means, so the criticism of finding means and standard deviations from ordinal data is not appropriate in this instance?

The only explicit assumption of PERMANOVA is exchangeability, but it also assumes linearity and there are some more hints on how to prepare the data, which are well described in this article and references within: Anderson, M.J., 2014. Permutational multivariate analysis of variance (PERMANOVA). Wiley statsref: statistics reference online, pp.1-15.

Comment: E.G. While homogeneity of variances (/group dispersions) isn't necessarily a requirement for PERMANOVA, it does directly influence the results, along with independence of data. Therefore, it would be valuable to run a PERMDISP (betadisper()) alongside PERMANOVA, because a significant output might mean that homogeneity of variances contribute to any observed differences in PERMANOVA (source: Primer manual for PERMANOVA).